# How do I keep a submenu open when clicked?

Tags: javascript, submenu

This was created by someone else, but some submenus stay open while one stays closed when clicked. I have an idea of what I can do, but I have very little knowledge of JS. I was thinking if `sub5` (the id for the submenu that stays closed), *"something to make it true, then false if not `sub5`"* How can I do this?

HTML

```
<nav id="rightNav">
    <div class="menutitle first" onClick="SwitchMenu('sub1')">fabrics</div>
    <div id="sub1" class="submenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="leejofa_fabrics.htm">lee jofa</a></li>
            <li><a href="groundworks_fabrics.htm">groundworks</a></li>
            <li><a href="threads_fabrics.htm">threads</a></li>
            <li><a href="gpjbaker_fabrics.htm">gp &amp; j baker</a></li>
            <li><a href="mulberryhome_fabrics.htm">mulberry home</a></li>
            <li><a href="lifestyle_fabrics.htm">baker lifestyle</a></li>
            <li><a href="blithfield_fabrics.htm">blithfield</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- end div#sub1 (fabrics) -->

    <div class="menutitle" onClick="SwitchMenu('sub2')">furniture</div>
    <div id="sub2" class="submenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="leejofa_upholstery.htm">lee jofa upholstery</a></li>
            <li><a href="leejofa_occasionals.htm">lee jofa occasionals</a></li>
            <li><a href="furniture/bunny_williams/bunny_williams.htm">Bunny Williams Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="../../hollandco.htm">holland &amp; co.</a></li>
            <li><a href="macrae_furniture.htm">macrae</a></li>
            <li><a href="elle_and_marks.htm">elle &amp; marks</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- end div#sub2 (furniture) -->

    <div class="menutitle" onClick="SwitchMenu('sub3')">wallcoverings</div>
    <div id="sub3" class="submenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="leejofa_wallcoverings.htm">lee jofa</a></li>
            <li><a href="coleson_wallcoverings.htm">cole &amp; son</a></li>
            <li><a href="groundworks_wallcoverings.htm">groundworks</a></li>
            <li><a href="wallcoverings/threads_wallcoverings_variation.htm">threads</a></li>
            <li><a href="gpjbaker_wallcoverings.htm">gP &amp; j baker</a></li>
            <li id="blithfield-wall"><a href="wallcoverings/blithfield_wallcoverings_peggy_angus.htm">blithfield</a></li>
            <li><a href="farrowandball_wallcoverings.htm">farrow &amp; ball</a></li>
            <li><a href="lincrusta_wallcoverings.htm">lincrusta</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- end div#sub3 (wallcoverings) -->

    <div class="menutitle"><a href="leejofa_trimmings.htm">trimmings</a></div>

    <div class="menutitle" onClick="SwitchMenu('sub5')">carpets</div>
    <div id="sub5" class="submenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="leejofa_carpet.htm">lee jofa carpet</a></li>
            <li id="gw-carpet"><a href="groundworks_carpet.htm">groundworks</a></li>
            <li><a href="threads_carpet.htm">threads</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- end div#sub5 (carpets) -->

    <div class="menutitle" id="archive-collection"><a href="leejofa_collections.htm">designer collections</a></div>

    <div class="menutitle last"><a href="leejofa_archive.htm">archives</a></div>

</nav>
<!-- end nav#rightNav -->
```

JS

```
if (document.getElementById) { //DynamicDrive.com change
    document.write('<style type="text/css">\n')
    document.write('.submenu{display: none;}\n')
    document.write('</style>\n')
}

function SwitchMenu(obj) {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        var el = document.getElementById(obj);
        var ar = document.getElementById("rightNav").getElementsByTagName("div"); //DynamicDrive.com change
        if (el.style.display != "block") { //DynamicDrive.com change
            for (var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
                if (ar[i].className == "submenu") //DynamicDrive.com change
                    ar[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            el.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            el.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maxim, I tried your changes, but there was no change.

Comment: it was formatting improvement to make your question readable

Comment: Does anything have to do with not having `sub4`? Trimmings does not have a submenu...and neither do the last two (Designer Collections and Archives).

Comment: Yes, I understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have a class and a style.

Your style is defined in the class, so you can't access it with element.style.

A simple solution is to change this line:

```
<div id="sub5" class="submenu">
```

to

```
<div id="sub5" class="submenu" style="display:none;">
```

Comment: I tried turning it on and off and it showed all the other submenus, so I think that is necessary to switch between them.

Comment: Do you have more div's with id="sub5"? this could cause this "effect"

Comment: I didn't see any duplicates. I edited my post to include all the submenus.

Comment: Try to debug your code (on IE, pressing F12)... I am sure there are more errors. This could stop your script. But also if you have the id sub5 twice it stops working.